# Laravel Issue with Policy not being triggered properly?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I have a route model binding like that:

```
Route::model('questionnaireAttachment', \App\Models\QuestionnaireAttachment::class);
```

I also have policy registered in AuthServiceProvider.php:

```
QuestionnaireAttachment::class => QuestionnaireAttachmentPolicy::class,
```

and the route I have is like this:

```
Route::get('questionnaire/attachments/{questionnaireAttachment}', [
    AttachmentController::class,
    'getAttachments'
])
->name('questionnaireAttachmentRetrieve')
->middleware('can:view,questionnaireAttachment');
```

the policy has return false; in it so I know it fails however when I make the request to the endpoint, despite the return false; i still get to the controller and I get a valid 200 response

```
 public function getAttachments(QuestionnaireAttachment $attachment): \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse
        {
            $file = Storage::disk('local')->exists("{$attachment->path}/{$attachment->filename}");
            if (!$file) {
                return Storage::disk('s3')->download("{$attachment->path}/{$attachment->filename}", $attachment->filename);
            }
            return Storage::disk('local')->download("{$attachment->path}/{$attachment->filename}", $attachment->filename);
        }
```

Comment: Can you add the header of your `AttachmentController::getAttachments()` method? Do you type-hint `QuestionnaireAttachment ` as parameter?

Comment: done that, check the edited question

Comment: Thank you for expanding your question. Can you add the code for `QuestionnaireAttachmentPolicy->view()`?

Comment: And do you have any `before` or `after` checks specified which might override your single policy?

Comment: Policy only has return false in it. there is before method that checks if user role = 1 which it isn't

Comment: Mh.. I tried to reproduce your example and it works as expected. Can you xdebug or `dd()` your `before` policy and double-check that it does `return void` instead of `true`/`false`?